# Visual Studio 2015 / VB.NET Intellisense not showing EVERY methods/variables

Tags: vb.net, variables, methods, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

First time for me here !

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. When, for exemple I enter the line for a form :

WaitingTickets.(list of methods/properties)

[Missing Stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btJ9H.png)

I get some, **but not all**. For exemple, it doesn't show WaitingTickets.**Show()** in the list.

Same with public variables, the list doesn't show public variables between forms.

The fun thing is, on one computer it work perfectly, and on this one it doesn't. No modification where done.

I tried the resetsettings, resetuserdata, remove .vs in project. No luck.

So if anyone have an idea !

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a minimal example? If you can, this could be a good basis for a bug report.

Comment: Have you by any chance recently gone over to Update1 of Visual Studio?  If so (and especially if it took an eternity to update then you might just be experiencing corruption in the vs kernel.  Had the same issue myself, complete uninstall followed by reinstall cured the problem.

Comment: @DomSinclair Yes it appears I installed with Update 1. Now you spoke of it, I have not update 1 on the first PC. 

But I tried to uninstall and reinstall without update 1, and bug still there. Maybe some files/config is still there !

Comment: @Heinzi 

A more basic exemple :

We have :
-Form1.vb
-Form2.vb

Usually, in Form2.vb code, you can do :
-  Form1.Show()  (it is listed as an option, as showdialog and many other methods)
- Form1.SomePublicVariable

Now, the problem is, you can still do it, but it DOESN'T APPEAR in the list (as shown in the screen).

Comment: Is your WaitingTikcets come from another library and show is private ?, just for check ?

Comment: @Anirugu Hmm not an expert, I don't think it is private. It is just another Form in my project. But even public variables do not appear.

Comment: @Jean-LaurentROUZIES: I understand that. Still, if you can provide a simple, *complete* repro example, you could file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this? I am having the same issue with VS2015 Community edition... It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @lucky.expert Hi, the only way I found : install an "old" version of Visual Studio without Update 1. But I think once update 1 is installed there is likely no way to make it work without ... well ... formating computer as I don't know what SP1 file or config create the "bug". As I said before I tried to remove update 1 and it doesn't fix it. I made a report to MS back in the time ... so just wait I guess :/

Comment: @Jean-Laurent ROUZIES : Did you fix the problem? How?