# Visual Studio 2015 (VB.NET) IntelliSense not showing variables, methods and properties

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Up to now IntelliSense listed all public variables, methods and properties of a class, when I used the name somewhere else, but now it only shows a few properties and methods. The problem also occurs with forms and other controls.

There is a post, which dealed already with this issue ([link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353411/visual-studio-2015-vb-net-intellisense-not-showing-every-methods-variables)), but it does not provide a working solution. Maybe someone knows the reason for this behaviour.

Edit: Here is a screenshot with an example:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Blackwood Are you asking for a screenshot?  Other than that, I don't know how someone could show an example of intellisense not working.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Not necessarily, an example would include the line of code in question and an explanation of what methods were not shown by Intellisense, and at what point in typing the line those methods were expected to be shown. That would be something that could be verified.

Comment: The default instance behavior of the Form class in vb.net has wrecked many programmer minds.  I kinda doubt the Roslyn team can be cajoled into fixing this.  You have a "no", maybe you'll get a "yes".  Click the New Issue button in [this web page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot the problem is easier to spot.  You are using the Default Instance of a form.  As Hans said, intellisense not displaying here is a probably a minor bug that Microsoft will likely not fix.  Your code is easier to fix however.  Don't use the default instance; it should look like this:

```
dim f as new Form1
f.Sub1 '<--- should get intellisense here now.
```

You should avoid using default instance of forms.  In my experience, they cause nothing but problems.  Creating a form instance, storing it in a local variable or field, and passing those references around is easy enough.  It's also a much better practice that will make your code stronger overall.

Comment: But until now it worked without Problems. Thats why I asked the question.
Was there maybe an update or something like that, because it actually changed from one day to the other.

Comment: If it is actually a bug as Hans suggested, then it could be triggered by almost anything.